# How to create a single Array Structure column for "multiple" individual DF/DS columns with Spark SCALA

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

## Say I have two table,`order_table` and `room_table`

order_table

```
+----------+---------+
| order_id | info    |
+----------+---------+
| order1   | infos   |
+----------+---------+
```

room_table with many columns

```
+----------+---------+-----+
| order_id | room_id | ... | 
+----------+---------+-----+
| order1   | room1   | ... |
| order1   | room2   | ... |
+----------+---------+-----+
```

I want to add `select * from room_table group by order_id` result as collect list to `order_table` new column `rooms`.

Output table should keep the schema:

```
-order_id string,
-info string,
-room array<struct>
 --room_id string,
 --room_price int,
 --room_name string
 -- ....
```

Comment: You just need a join, https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins.html

Comment: simple join can't solve my problem, key point is add `group by results as one sub row` to column

Comment: We cannot see the output, please provide that.

Comment: I added in post,Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    val df1 = Seq(("order_1", "order_1_info"),
              ("order_2", "order_2_info")).toDF("order_id", "info")
    val df2 = Seq(("order_1", "room_1", 100, "palace_1"),
              ("order_2", "room_2", 200, "palace_2"),
              ("order_1", "room_3", 100, "palace_3"),
              ("order_2", "room_8", 200, "palace_x"))
              .toDF("order_id", "room_id", "room_price", "room_name")
    val cols: Array[String] = df2.columns
    val df3 = df2.groupBy("order_id").agg(collect_list(struct(cols.head, cols.tail:_*)) as "room")
    val df4 = df1.join(df3, Seq("order_id"))
    df4.show()
    df4.printSchema()
```

In above snippet, I just made some sample dataframes for use.

Output : -

```
+--------+------------+--------------------+
|order_id|        info|                room|
+--------+------------+--------------------+
| order_1|order_1_info|[[order_1,room_1,...|
| order_2|order_2_info|[[order_2,room_2,...|
+--------+------------+--------------------+
```

Schema:-

```
root
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: string (nullable = true)
 |-- room: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- room_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- room_price: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- room_name: string (nullable = true)
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Very Helpful! Thank You!

Comment: Really like this!